# Proof without words of the Quadratic Formula?

Tags: geometry, quadratics, conic-sections, education, visualization

As suggested by @Moti and @YvesDaoust in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2997349/559615), a simple way to identify the roots (red dots) of a parabola (given focus and directrix, blue) by means of straightedge and compass is to draw the circle with center in the focus and radius the distance $\overline{HI}$ between the $x$-axis and the directrix.

[image]

Now, consider the Quadratic Formula

$$
\color{red}{x_{\pm}}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a \cdot \mathbf{c} }}{2a}.
$$

In the above image (a part the roots), it is easy to spot the term $\mathbf{c}$, i.e. the intercept of the parabola with the $y$-axis.

My question is:

> How to *geometrically* illustrate the other various algebraic terms of the quadratic formula by means of this construction, is such a way that the algebraic relation results immediately evident?

With *geometrically*, I mean some visual intuition, based on such plot (or something similar), in the spirit of a "proof without words".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: An obvious interpretation of one of the terms is that $-b/2a$ is the x coordinate of the vertex and thus the location of point H.

Comment: @DanielGendin The more obvious, the better! Thanks!

Comment: I prefer to write the quadratic formula as $x=\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{-b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{c}{a}}$. Thanks to Daniel's comment we already know what $-b/2a$ is. Now there is only $c/a$ left to explain.

Comment: @Rahul True. Good observation. But "where" is $a$? Of course, I know that it is the amplitude of the parabola, but I cannot easily show its exact value on this plot. However, $c/a$ suggests me the ratio between two sides of a triangle...

Comment: Unfortunately $c/a$ has units of area, so it's going to be tricky.

Comment: @Rahul Right. I tried to work this out.

Comment: @Rahul Maybe it would be easier to visualize the discriminant?

Comment: I don't see how. But here's an observation: The tangent from the $y$-intercept meets the $x$-axis at a point $J$ with abscissa $-c/b$. Then $2|OH|\,|OJ|=2(-b/2a)(-c/b)=c/a$. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: @Rahul Looks promising! I check what we can do we this! Thanks!!!

Comment: I think it boils down to this: What's a geometrical interpretation of $\sqrt{|OH|^2 - 2|OH|\,|OJ|}$? Possibly relevant: $\sqrt{|OH|\,|OJ|}$ can be constructed geometrically via https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:01-Mittlere_Proportionale.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slight re-packaging of notions from [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2999917/409).

---

[image]

> $$|OQ_{\pm}| \;=\; |BB_{-}| \pm |MQ_{+}| \;=\;-\frac{b}{2a} \pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{c}{a}} \;=\; \frac{1}{2a} \left(\;-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}\;\right)$$

---

- The figure represents the scenario in which $a>0$, $b\leq 0$, $c\geq 0$ (and thus that $|OM|\geq |MQ_{\pm}|$). Adjustments to accommodate various sign changes should be clear.
- Figure labels and calculations incorporate the fact that the latus rectum has length $1/a$.
- That $\overline{OM} \cong \overline{BB_{-}}$ is my previous answer's Property 2. That these segments' common signed length is $-b/(2a)$ follows, as before, from the equation of the represented parabola, by calculating the difference in $y$-coordinates for points with $x$-coordinates $\pm 1/(4a)$.
- The relation between the highlighted areas follows immediately from my previous answer's Property 1. Stripping away the trappings of the specific problem, we can state the area property as a general principle that @Andrea should appreciate:

> **Property 1a.** If squares are erected upon axis-perpendicular semi-chords of a parabola, then the difference in their areas is the area of the rectangle bounded by those chords and the extremities of the parabola's latus rectum.

[image]

---

By the way, here's a proof-without-words for my previous question's Property 2, using Property 1a above.

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. I'm trying to reproduce this with geogebra. Looks great!

Comment: This is the closest to a proof without words. Should be put in the textbooks!

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto: Thanks! I'm pretty happy with it. I even learned a couple of new things about parabolas along the way. :)

Answer (score 3):

This solution isn't nearly as self-evident as I like my illustrations to be, but there are some interesting ideas here.

I'll preface this by noting, in something of an echo of @Rahul's comment, that geometricizing $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is a little tricky, in that $a$, $b$, $c$ are dimensionally distinct. In the approach described below, we take $x$ and $y$ (and thus also the roots of the quadratic equation) to be represented by ($1$-dimensional) lengths; necessarily, we see that $c$ must also be $1$-dimensional, $b$ must be $0$-dimensional (a ratio), and $a$ must be ... $(-1)$-dimensional!

---

Suppose that the graph of $y=ax^2+bx+c$ represents an upward-facing parabola with vertex $V= (h,-k)$; that is, we take $a$ positive and $b$ non-positive. Let $f$ be the vertex-to-focus distance, $f := |VF|$. Let the parabola cross the $y$-axis at $C$, of distance $c\geq0$ from the origin (although it's less problematic here to allow $c<0$), and let the parabola cross the $x$-axis at $R_{\pm}$, at distances $h\pm s$ from the origin.

Some auxiliary points: Let the $x$-axis and parabola axis meet at $M$ (the midpoint of $R_{+}$ and $R_{-}$). Let the horizontal line through $V$ meet the $x$-axis at $k$, and let $S$ be the projection of $R_{+}$ onto that line (so $|VK|=h$, $|VS|=s$, and $|OK|=|SR_{+}|=k$). Also, let the lines $x=\pm f$ meet the parabola at $B_{\pm}$, and let $B$ complete the right triangle with hypotenuse joining those points. Points $A$ and $G$ are on the $y$-axis and parabola axis such that $|KA|=|VG|=4f$.

Given the above, the below *happens* to be an illustration of the Quadratic Formula:

[image]

As I mentioned: not nearly as self-evident as I like. The illustration relies on two interesting properties of parabolas that derive from the reflection property; I'll prove them later.

> **Property 1.** If $P$ is a point on the ("vertical") parabola, then its *horizontal* displacement from the vertex is the *geometric mean* of $4f$ and its vertical displacement from the vertex.

The illustration includes two instances of this property in the form of a classical right-triangle construction of the geometric mean.

$$\begin{align}
\triangle AVC: &\quad \frac{|KV|}{|KA|} = \frac{|KC|}{|KV|} \quad\to\quad |KV|^2=|KA||KC|\quad\to\quad h^2=4f(c+k) \tag{1} \\[6pt]
\triangle GSM: &\quad \frac{|VS|}{|VG|} = \frac{|VM|}{|VS|} \quad\to\quad 
|VS|^2=|VG||VM| \quad\to\quad s^2=4fk \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From these, we may conclude $s^2 = h^2 - 4fc$, so that the $x$-coordinates of $R_{\pm}$ ---that is, the roots of the quadratic polynomial--- have the form
$$h\;\pm\;\sqrt{h^2-4fc} \tag{3}$$

(As an aside: Let the circumcircle $\bigcirc R_{+} R_{-} C$ meet the $y$-axis again at, say, $D$. Then the [power of a point theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point), applied to the origin with respect to this circle, imply $$|OR_{+}||OR_{-}| = (h+s)(h-s) = c\cdot 4f = |OC||OD|$$
If we could show independently that $|OD| = 4f$, then we could reason conversely to get $(3)$ without the separate geometric means. I don't see an obvious way to make that association, however ... although little about this approach is obvious.)

Now, $(3)$ bears a bit of a resemblance to the Quadratic Formula. To get it closer, we invoke another property:

> **Property 2.** If $P$, and distinct points $Q_{+}$ and $Q_{-}$, are on a ("vertical") parabola, such that the *horizontal* displacement from $P$ to each $Q$ is $f$, then the *vertical* displacement between the $Q$s is the distance from $P$ to the axis of the parabola.

In the figure above, $C$ plays the role of $P$, and $B_\pm$ the roles of $Q_{\pm}$. Since our parabola represents $y=ax^2+bx+c$, we have that $B_{\pm}$ is at (signed) distance $af^2\pm bf+c$ from the $x$-axis; thus, the vertical displacement between them is simply the difference of these expressions. By Property 2, we can write
$$h = \left(\;af^2-bf+c\;\right) - \left(\;af^2+bf+c\;\right) = -2bf \tag{4}$$ 
(Recall that $b$ is non-negative here.) Therefore, $(3)$ becomes
$$-2bf\;\pm\;\sqrt{4b^2f^2-4cf} \tag{5}$$
which we can write as
$$2f\left(\;-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-\frac{c}{f}}\;\right) \tag{6}$$
In light of the "known" observation that $a = \dfrac{1}{4f}$ (there's that $(-1)$-dimensionality we needed!), we see
$$\frac{1}{2a}\left(\;-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\;\right) \tag{7}$$
so that we do, in fact, have the Quadratic Formula. $\square$

I'm a little disappointed in the algebraic manipulations required in this demonstration. Perhaps a second pass at the argument, drawing from some more sophisticated geometric properties of parabolas, will streamline things.

---

Here are proofs of the Properties ...

> **Property 1.**

[image]

Here, $\overline{DW}$ is the directrix of the parabola, so that $\triangle PFD$ is isosceles. The reflection property of parabolas implies that the tangent at $P$ bisects the angle at $P$; it therefore also bisects base $\overline{FD}$ at a point $M$ that, by a simple similarity argument, also serves as the midpoint of $\overline{BV}$. From similar subtriangles within $\triangle PMD$, we have
$$\frac{|BM|}{|BD|}=\frac{|BP|}{|BM|} \quad\to\quad \left(\frac12 q\right)^2=fp \quad\to\quad q^2 = 4f\cdot p$$
giving the result. $\square$

> **Property 2.**

[image]

Again, $\overline{DW}$ is the directrix. This time, we use the reflection property relative to $P$ to conclude that the tangent at $P$ is perpendicular to $\overline{FD}$. It is "known" that chord $\overline{Q_{+}Q_{-}}$ is parallel to that tangent. With a little angle chasing, we find that we may conclude $\triangle Q_{+}QQ_{-}\cong \triangle FWD$, and the property follows. $\square$

Comment: What an amazing work, @Blue. I am reading it. Thanks for this effort, I am also trying something, but now I am afraid that I would not be able produce anything simpler!

Comment: How do you know that chord $Q_{+}Q_{-}$ is parallel to the tangent?

Comment: @mihirb: Proving that chord $Q_+Q_-$ is parallel to the tangent is a super-easy exercise in Calculus, but that seems a little heavy-handed here. I don't recall a synthetic proof off the top of my head, but if you believe that the midpoints of parallel chords are parallel to the parabola's axis, then you can interpret the result as saying that the point where the "line of midpoints" of a family of parallel chords meets the parabola is like an "infinitely small" member of that family, and that the line through it (that is, the tangent line at that point) is parallel to those chords.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients $a,b,c$ of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx^2+c=0$ are not very geometric, so let's work with some slightly different variables that do have a geometric meaning:
\begin{align}
\alpha &= -\frac b{2a}, & \beta &= -\frac cb, & \gamma &= c.
\end{align}
In reverse order, $C=(0,\gamma)$ is the $y$-intercept of the parabola, $B=(\beta,0)$ is the point where the tangent through $C$ meets the $x$-axis, and $A=(\alpha,0)$ is the point on the $x$-axis with the same $x$-coordinate as the parabola's focus. The parabola is specified via $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, and we need to find the points $P$ and $Q$ where it crosses the $x$-axis.

[image]

<sup>Blue: given data, gray: constructed, green: equal quantities, red: desired roots</sup>

Denote the focus by $F$ and the intersection of the directrix and the $y$-axis by $D$.

1. Construct the line $CF$ using the property of the parabola that the tangent $CB$ bisects $\angle OCF$. Obtain $F$ as the intersection of $CF$ and the vertical through $A$.
2. Obtain $D$ using the fact that $C$ is equidistant from $F$ and $D$. The directrix is the horizontal through $D$, and is at distance $|OD|$ from the $x$-axis.
3. Obtain $P$ and $Q$ as the points on the $x$-axis at distance $|OD|$ from $F$.

$P$ and $Q$ are equidistant from $F$ and the directrix, and so lie on the parabola.

---

To derive the quadratic formula from this, we take an additional step, which may or may not be acceptable from a pure Euclidean-geometry perspective: We note that moving $C$ along the $y$-axis doesn't change the location of the roots, since it just scales the parabola vertically about the $x$-axis. Therefore, we may choose $C$ freely to simplify the construction.

In particular, let us take $C=(0,\beta)$. Then $\angle OCB=45^\circ$, so the line $CF$ is horizontal, and $F=(\alpha,\beta)$. Now $|CD|=|CF|=\alpha$, so $|OD|=\alpha-\beta$. The right triangle $\triangle AFP$ has hypotenuse $|FP|=|OD|=\alpha-\beta$ and vertical side $|AF|=\beta$, so the horizontal side is $|AP|=\sqrt{(\alpha-\beta)^2-\beta^2}=\sqrt{\alpha^2-2\alpha\beta}$; the same is true for $|AQ|$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\{|OP|,|OQ|\} &= |OA| \pm |AP| \\
&= \alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2-2\alpha\beta}.
\end{align}

[image]

Plug in the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from above, and you obtain the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

As the Wikipedia article [Power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) indicates, the tangent to the circle from the origin distance squared is the product of the two roots, but this is just $\,c/a.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not know this, and I am reading about!

Comment: ... But I can I visualize this onto the above construction, in the context of the Quadratic Formula, I mean?

Comment: I'm working on it.