# The role of the coefficients in a parabola $\mathcal{P}: y=ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, conic-sections, education

If I have a parabola $\mathcal{P}: y=ax^2+bx+c$, I know that $a$ provides me with the aperture of the parabola; $c$ is the known term. If it is zero the parabola passes through the origin otherwise not.

> What is the role or the meaning that can be given to $b$ in the description of a parabola?

Comment: Both $b$ and $c$ are related to the position of the vertex.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes of course.  Is $b$ a kind of "shift" for a parabola?

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): ["Proof without words of the Quadratic Formula"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2998671/409). See in particular [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2999917/409) or [my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3002555/409), which interpret the coefficients geometrically. (I'll admit, the figures are a little overwhelming! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice the degree of the term involving $b$, you can deduce that there should be some connection to a line with equation $\mathcal{L}:y=bx+c$.

Specifically, $b$ is the slope of $\mathcal{L}$, which is always the tangent to $\mathcal{P}$ at the point $(0,c)$.
We can see this algebraically by taking the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2+bx+c)=2ax+b$ and plugging $x=0$ to obtain a constant slope $b$.

You can imagine that adjusting $b$ forces the parabola to move in a wave-like pattern to "match" its tangent line if that makes any sense.

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2ut8sawr26) is an interactive graph with both the tangent $\mathcal{L}$ and parabola $\mathcal{P}$ in view. Notice that adjusting $a$ does not affect the tangent.

Comment: Thank you very much. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think as you said in the comments it has a role on "shiftting" the parabola in the x-y plane since it partially determines the coordinates of the vertex.
Also $b$ is related to the location of the zeros of the parabola so you know that if $b$ equals zero the parabola will be symmetrical respect the $y$-axis.

Hope it helps, have a good evening.

Comment: Thank you very much. +1

Answer (score 1):

I look upon things differently.

If $~y = ax^2 + bx + c,~$

then $~\displaystyle \frac{y}{a} = x^2 + \frac{b}{a} ~x + \frac{c}{a} = \left( ~x + \frac{b}{2a} ~\right)^2 + \frac{4ac - b^2}{4a^2}.~$

Assigning variables:

- $~\displaystyle M = \frac{b}{2a},$
- $~\displaystyle D = \frac{4ac - b^2}{4a^2},$

you then have that

$$\frac{y}{a} = \left( ~x + M ~\right)^2 + D. \tag1 $$

Then, the graph of $~y~$ can be constructed from the graph of $~y = x^2,~$ by:

- Shifting the graph $~M~$ units to the left.
- Then shifting the graph $~D~$ units up.
- Then stretching the graph by the factor $~a.$

Comment: Very nice and I am grateful. +1